# Nesting multiple IFS

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, nested

I have the following formula which works fine:

```
=IF(AND(Input!$G$54="",Input!$I$54="",Input!$K$54="",Input!$K$56),0,IF(AND(Input!$I$54="",Input!$K$54="", Input!$K$56=""),B20*Input!$G$54*Lookups!AF4,IF(AND(Input!$G$54="",Input!$K$54="", Input!$K$56=""),Lookups!AM2*$J$5*Lookups!AF4,IF(AND(Input!$G$54="",Input!$I$54=""),SUM(B20*Input!$K$54*Lookups!AF4,Lookups!AM2*$J$5*Lookups!AF4)))))
```

But I need to add the following condition to one of the equations, which appears twice in the formula.

```
=IF(Lookups!$A$O2<30,Lookups!AM2*$J$5*Lookups!AF4,0)
```

I've input dashes ------- where the above needs to go.

```
=IF(AND(Input!$G$54="",Input!$I$54="",Input!$K$54="",Input!$K$56),0,IF(AND(Input!$I$54="",Input!$K$54="", Input!$K$56=""),B20*Input!$G$54*Lookups!AF4,IF(AND(Input!$G$54="",Input!$K$54="", Input!$K$56=""),-------Lookups!AM2*$J$5*Lookups!AF4-------,IF(AND(Input!$G$54="",Input!$I$54=""),SUM(B20*Input!$K$54*Lookups!AF4,-------Lookups!AM2*$J$5*Lookups!AF4-------)))))
```

Whatever way I try to add this I get the 'not trying to type a formula' error. Please can someone help?

Comment: Can you include sample data with expected output please? Easier to understand formulae that way and you may find that people come up with easier solutions.

Comment: The issue is that `$A$O2` is not valid. Perhaps you meant: `$AO$2`?

Comment: Thank you JvdV and Rory - the problem was that I'd mistyped as per Rory's comment. It's working now. I feel quite silly!